# Haskell ADT declares floats, but ADT instance definition fails to compile when provided with floats

Tags: haskell

I've written this simple module which exposes the ADT's `Point` and `Shape`:

```
module Lib(Point, Shape) where

data Point = Point Float Float deriving (Show)
data Shape = Circle Point Float | Rectangle Point Point deriving (Show)
```

Then, I have written a main which defines an instance of `Circle`:

```
module Main where

import Lib

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let circle = Circle 0.0 0.0 10.0
  print ""
```

However, it fails to compile with the error message:

```
    Data constructor not in scope:
      Circle :: Double -> Double -> Double -> t
  |
7 |   let circle = Circle 0 0 10
  |                ^^^^^^
```

From what I've read, I was under the impression that Haskell compiler would infer the type based on the ADT definition, for instance I should be able to write main like this and have it compile:

```
module Main where

import Lib

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let circle = Circle 0 0 10
  print ""
```

But then that fails with a similar message:

```
    Data constructor not in scope:
      Circle :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> t
  |
7 |   let circle = Circle 0 0 10
  |                ^^^^^^
```

Is there anyone who can break this down for me so I can understand why it's not working?

Comment: You did not export the data constructors.

Comment: I thought I did? I exported the ADT itself (i.e. Shape and Point). Do I need to export the actual data constructors (i.e. Rectangle, Circle, Point) instead? I've just tried that now and got an error "Not in scope: Type constructor or class Circle".

Comment: no, you only exported the type. Sometimes you do not want to export the constructors, for example to prevent people from calling these directly.

Comment: "not in scope" in the error message should tell you that this is nothing to do with floats or type inference. It means the compiler has no idea what `Circle` is (in this case, because you didn't export it, so it couldn't be imported), so it doesn't know what to do with *any* usage of `Circle`, correct arguments or not. So next time you see an error saying something is "not in scope", look for typos in the name, problems with imports/exports, etc, not problems with types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only made the `Lib` module export the *types*, not the corresponding data constructors, you can export these with:

```
module Lib(Point(..), Shape(..)) where

-- ...
```

or more verbose:

```
module Lib(Point(Point), Shape(Circle, Rectangle)) where

-- ...
```

Note that the above still will not work correctly since your `Circle` takes a `Point` and a `Float`. It thus should be:

```
    let circle = Circle (Point 0 0) 10
```